# python - basic write to file code not working

Tags: python

I write a basic file write code -

```
    f = open('workfile', 'r+')

    f.write('0123456789abcdef')
```

I run the file at cmd at the same folder where I put `workfile.txt` file but I get the error -

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'workfile'

I tried also to convert to exe file with py2exe and run the exe file but nothing...

what is the problem?

thanks!

====================

the full error massage when check on compiler-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                               
    File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/.c9/metadata/workspace/2.py", line 1, in     <module>                                                                                 
    f = open('workfile', 'r+')                                                                                                                                   
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'workfile'
```

Comment: you missed the file extension in your code

Comment: Do you have a file called `workfile`?  No, it's called `workfile.txt`.

Comment: With `"r+"` mode, the file must already exist. Obviously, `"workfile"` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename 'workfile' to 'workfile.txt':

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'r+')
```